# Airflow DAG Multiple Runs

Tags: airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have a DAG that I want to run multiple times after each successful completion.  For an example I want to run it 10 times and stop.  Is there a way to accomplish this?  I tried looking into scheduling with CRON but it doesn't seem clean nor triggering the DAG via UI multiple times doesn't work (runs in parallel).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution to my use case.  It incorporated using **depends_on_past=True** (*mentioned by @Hitesh Gupta*) and setting your **airflow.cfg** file below:

`# The maximum number of active DAG runs per DAG
max_active_runs_per_dag = 1`

This allowed us to only have one active DAG run at a time and also to not continue the next DAG run if there were failure in the previous run. This is for Airflow version 1.10.1 that I tested on.

Answer (score 0):

- You can, in addition to supplying a `start_date`, provide your DAG an `end_date`
- Quoting the [docstring](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/models/dag.py#L101)

> `:param start_date`: The timestamp from which the scheduler will attempt
>   to backfill
>
> `:type start_date`: datetime.datetime
>
> `:param end_date:` A date beyond which your DAG won't run, leave to None for open ended scheduling
>
> `:type end_date`: datetime.datetime

---

While unrelated, also have a look at following `scheduler` settings in [`airflow.cfg`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/config_templates/default_airflow.cfg#L493) as mentioned in [this](https://medium.com/@kass09/airflow-scheduler-and-broken-dags-8fdbe8054725) article

- `run_duration`
- `num_runs`

---

**UPDATE-1**

- In his article [Use apache airflow to run task exactly once](https://medium.com/@plieningerweb/use-apache-airflow-to-run-task-exactly-once-6fb70ca5e7ec), **@Andreas P** has described a clever technique, which I believe can be adapted to your use-case. While even that won't be a very-tidy solution, it would at-least allow you to specify beforehand the number of runs (integer) for DAG instead of `end_date`.
- Alternatively (assuming you implement the above approach) rather than rather than baking this skipping-dag-after max-runs functionality within each DAG, you can create a separate *orchestrator DAG* that disables a given DAG after its max runs have passed.

Comment: The only problem I see with supplying start and end date is that it's not clean and we can only estimate our jobs run times and fiddle around with start and end date.  I'm looking for a clean solution which a DAG should run x number of times sequentially. I looked into your links regarding the `Scheduler`, it doesn't mentioned if this is a global setting for all DAGS for `run_duration` and `num_runs`?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set property ***depends_on_past***. This is set under DAG's default arguments section and it refers to previous instance dag instance. This is fix your problem.

Comment: What I observed through this property setting in Airflow 1.10.1, even though you set it at a DAG's default argument, it still runs at a Task level.  I.e. you queue up a DAG with 2 tasks in it via manually triggering on the UI multiple times, you can observe that DAG[1] (instance of the first DAG run) as soon as the 1st task completed successfully DAG[2] task 1 will start, and this behavior continues with task2 as long as the previous Task was successful.  The desired behavior is to have DAG[1] completely finish its tasks successfully before DAG[2] starts.